# Is there a map with kernel $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> Is there $\phi\in\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ such that the kernel of $\phi$ is $\mathbb{Q}$?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, can you think of a natural way to embed the rationals?

Comment: For any infinite-dimensional $K$-vector space $V$, we can construct a linear map $V \to V$ with one-dimensional kernel (Of course we could need AC here).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft, I think all the rationals come to 0. And every irrational whose difference is rational should have the same value. But how we pick the representative?

Comment: @ MooS, What is AC?

Comment: axiom of choice. We need it to make sure that every vector space is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. Start with $1\in\mathbb R$ and notice that this is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$: $q\cdot 1=0\Rightarrow q=0$ for any $q\in\mathbb Q$. It is well known that in  vector space any linearly independent system can be extended to a basis. Thus we get a $\mathbb Q$-basis of $\mathbb R$ containing $1$. Now define a linear map $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\phi$ is identity on all the elements of the basis excepting $1$, and set $\phi(1)=0$. Then $\phi(q)=q\phi(1)=0$ for $q\in\mathbb Q$. If $x\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$, then $x=q\cdot 1+y$, where $y\ne0$ is a linear combination of the elements of basis different from $1$. In this case $\phi(x)=\phi(y)=y$. In conclusion, $\ker\phi=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: It's a good answer. Thanks! I get it.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\Bbb Q$ is a field, $\Bbb R$ is $\Bbb Q$-free, and of infinite range, say indexed by $I\sqcup \{1\}$. Then write $\Bbb R=\Bbb Q\oplus \bigoplus_{I} \Bbb Q$. Take the map that kills the first factor.

Comment: Thanks! But why $\mathbb{R}$ can be written in this way? Why we need $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-free?

Comment: I think I get what you say. Thanks!